macOS or Brew unlinked my Brew installed Python
I have been using brew for a lot of years and have not seen this issue -- yet.
On both Macs I have (a 2019 Intel Mac Pro and a M3 MacBook Pro) my Brew installed python@3.12 as well as all other versions stopped working as expected.
Since I have not used Python for a few months, I don't know quite when this stopped working but certainly I have done both OS upgrades and brew updates in the interim.
I have installed these formulae:
% brew list | grep python@
python@3.10
python@3.11
python@3.12
python@3.9

It used to be that this is how it worked:

If I typed python3 the most recent installed brew installed version would run;
If I typed pip3 the associated pip for the most recent install would run;
The shebang #!/usr/bin/env python3 would run most recent version;
The shebang of /usr/local/opt/python@[version_I_want]/python3 would run that version.

Recently, all that is broken.

Typing python3 at command line now gives me the SYSTEM version of python3;
Typing pip3 same -- the SYSTEM version of pip;
The links for python3 inside each version have been removed.
The link /usr/local/bin/python3 -> /usr/local/... is not a link anymore. This link usually was created by brew during the install.

I have tried running:
$ brew unlink python@3.12 && brew link python@3.12

but this did not restore the links. I have also uninstalled each package and reinstalled with brew.
I suppose I could do those links manually but since they were removed systematically by something, I am reluctant to do so. And that seems to defeat the purpose of the package manager.
My $PATH correctly points to the relevant brew managed directories first and the system directories last.
The Ruby and Perl I have managed by brew work as expected.
Any ideas?

Not the answer you're looking for, but uninstall all of the brew managed python versions and instead use brew to install pyenv. This will let you manage versions on a per project basis, while still having a default system level version of your choosing.

May need to do that -- especially with brew now enforcing system management on python@3.12+. Painful for an occasional Python user.

Have you considered MacPorts? It seems to be a bit more forgiving imho.

I installed Sonoma on my 2019 Intel Mac Pro yesterday and installed python@3.12 from python.org, here is what I did :
1) Make sure that /usr/local/bin is the first in $PATH in ~/.bashrc
   PATH=/usr/local/bin:...

2) cd /usr/local/bin
   mv python python.backup
   mv python3 python3.backup
   ln -fs python3.12 python3
   ln -fs python3    python

3) Use [python -m pip install] instead of using [pip install]

Hope above procedure can be useful, if any problem, you can always restore original links.
